# is there a way to store subsets of web.config in a separate folder outside of web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, web-config

I'm using a simple Publish process to publish my Web API 2 app to different environments. Different environments should use different database connection strings. Is there a creative way for me to split out certain Web.config info in environnment-specific configuration files?  For example, is it possible to break out the connectionStrings property like this into its own external file that would not get overridden?:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyAppDBConnString" connectionString="X />
</connectionStrings>
```

Also, is it possible to store this outside of the Web app so a basic "Publish All" from source wouldn't override the broken-out configuration file?  I.e., could I store this Web.config subset file somewhere on a random file directory outside of the primary web directory which contains all of the files for the web app?

Comment: Check this article out. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/BestPracticesForPrivateConfigDataAndConnectionStringsInConfigurationInASPNETAndAzure.aspx

Comment: you would basically have the settings in another file and reference it from the main config file. it works for app settings and connection strings. should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML transforms to modify your web.config on publish.

In Visual Studio, you can create a new build configuration, then right click the web.config file, and choose to create a new transform.

You should then be able to expand the web.config in Solution Explorer, and you will see a different config for each publish profile, that is named as Web.ProfileName.config

If you need a primer on XML transform syntax, go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx).  You likely want to use replace on your connectStrings element.

After that, you should see the changes when you publish.